# How to make the text file have the same number of whitespaces in order to make it into a dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I figured out how to make my text file into a dictionary but there is problem that is occurring.
This is an example text file:

pig: animal

dog: animal

cat:animal

car: thing

When I convert this into a dictionary I get: {" animal": ['pig','dog'], "animal" : ["cat"], " thing" : ['car']}

I need the cat to go with the pig and dog: {" animal": ["pig', 'dog', 'cat']} but since there is no space after the colon in the text file my program is not recognizing the key is still the same.

Thank you, any help is needed!

Comment: Post this as a working script. You want to normalize input, maybe `.strip().lower()` but exactly where... well, that's where your code comes into the picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all space after ':'. So, every value will have no space after column(:).
For example:

```
   with open('test.txt', mode='r') as file:
       text = file.read()
   clean_text = re.sub(r':( )+', ':', text)
  
   with open('output.txt', 'w') as file_out:
       file_out.write(clean_text)
```

so for Input:

```
   pig: animal

dog:     animal

cat:animal

car: thing
```

Output:

```
   pig:animal

dog:animal

cat:animal

car:thing
```

Answer (score 0):

You could process the file and fix the colon space problem:

```py
file = open('your_text.txt', mode='r')
text = file.read()
text = re.sub(r':(\w)', r': \1', text)
file.close()

with open('your_text.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    file_out.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this by using the `strip` method if you do not wish to create a new output file.

```
a = {}

with open("text.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        text = line.partition(":")
        value, key = text[0].strip(), text[2].strip()
        a.setdefault(key, [])
        a[key] += [value]

print(a)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One of the appraches:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = ['pig: animal', 'dog: animal', 'cat:animal', 'car: thing']
out = defaultdict(list)
for entry in data:
    entry_data = entry.split(':')
    out[entry_data[1].strip()].append(entry_data[0].strip())

print (out)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'animal': ['pig', 'dog', 'cat'], 'thing': ['car']})
```